# Ruby: how do I set the foreground terminal process group (posix tcsetpgrp)?

Tags: ruby, posix

I know that this has been asked a bunch of different ways and I am able to achieve what I want in C and Python, but I need to do this in Ruby; however, I'm not seeing support for tcsetpgrp in any documentation or on Google.  I even went as far as try to create a C wrapper for the the posix function, but can't find the .so.

In short, I want to add code to a Ruby script that will:

1. put itself (or better still, a subprocess it creates) in a different process group than its parent (like posix setpgrp)
2. make this new process group foreground in the controlling terminal (like posix tcsetpgrp),

I'll include my Python code, which will likely explain this better and show how simple a task this should be.  I'm not looking for a complete solution, but more so a solution for tcsetpgrp beeing missing in Ruby 2.6.5... is there a different function or approach for this?  How can create a wrapper to call the posix function described in the man page?

Thanks in advance!

tcgetpgrp:

```
NAME
       tcgetpgrp, tcsetpgrp - get and set terminal foreground process group

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       pid_t tcgetpgrp(int fd);

       int tcsetpgrp(int fd, pid_t pgrp);
```

My Python3 code:

```
def App.become_tty_fg
  '''This function, when used like:
  suprocess.Popen(..., preexec_fn=become_tty_fg)
  will force the child into a new process group and
  also force the child process group to be the foreground process group in the
  controlling terminal. The affect will be that that only the child will
  receive a ctrl-c generated SIGNINT because the parent is now backgrounded in a
  different process group and the child process group is foreground.  Signals
  reach all memebers of a proces group but ctrl-c originates in the foreground
  process group, so the child must be foreground in the terminal and in its own
  process group to protect the parent from an ctrl-c generated SIGINT.
  '''
  # create new process group for the child and put it in it.
  os.setpgrp()

  # Supress handling of SIGTTOU which would otherwise stop the
  # child proc when the terminal process group is changed.
  # The return value is the current handler for SIGTTOU.
  hdlr = signal.signal(signal.SIGTTOU, signal.SIG_IGN)

  # Need the terminal handle to use tcsetpgrp()
  tty = os.open('/dev/tty', os.O_RDWR)

  # change the foreground process in the terminal to the child
  os.tcsetpgrp(tty, os.getpgrp())

  # restore handling of SIGTTOU in case the child needs to be stopped (ctrl-z)
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTTOU, hdlr)
  tty.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty much direct line by line translation of your python code.

Since ruby does not implement `tcsetpgrp`, the easiest solution is to use the [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi) gem to bind to it, either via `gem install ffi` or adding FFI to your project `Gemfile`.

```rb
require 'ffi'

# This is our FFI binding to our system libc.
module C
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'c'

  # 'int tcsetpgrp(int, pid_t)'.
  # glibc defines pid_t as an int, apparently, so use that.
  # this may be system/os dependent!
  attach_function :tcsetpgrp, [:int, :int], :int
end

Process.setpgrp

prev = Signal.trap('SIGTTOU', 'IGNORE')

tty = File.open('/dev/tty', 'r')

rc = C.tcsetpgrp(tty.fileno, Process.getpgrp)

Signal.trap('SIGTTOU', prev)

tty.close
```

References:

- [Signal.trap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Signal.html)
- [Process.setpgrp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Process.html)
- [IO.fileno](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/IO.html)

Comment: Bingo, the `ffi_lib 'c'` is the piece I was missing.  Let me try this out see if that works.  Thank you very much for you quick response John!